# Is there a method to find the command time ? or a file changed times?

Tags: linux

I want to list my host server's history commands time.

I know use the `export HISTTIMEFORMAT="[%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S]"` in `/etc/profile` I can record the time in history, but if I want to list the command time before configured to `/etc/profile`.

Is there other method to find the command time? or a file changed times?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of things you can do to log command times, the easiest being accounting (cf. `man accton`), but all of them have to be turned on explicitly.  If you didn't turn on accounting first there is no way to tell *which* commands have run in the past, let alone when.

Answer (score 0):

The file times can easiest be viewed using `stat`, eg:

```
$ stat Vagrantfile
  File: 'Vagrantfile'
  Size: 3090            Blocks: 4          IO Block: 65536  regular file
Device: a0d483c6h/2698281926d   Inode: 11258999068526935  Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (1864414/ VW25G2A)   Gid: (1049089/ UNKNOWN)
Access: 2017-10-17 14:14:29.209303600 +0200
Modify: 2017-10-17 14:14:29.209303600 +0200
Change: 2017-10-17 14:14:29.209303600 +0200
 Birth: 2017-10-17 13:36:14.303951300 +0200
```